# Dynamical system $f(x)=x^4\sin(1/x)$. How to determine the stability of each equilibrium point?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Dynamical system $f(x)=x^4\sin(1/x)$ (for x not equal to zero) and $f(x)=0$ (for x=0). 
How to find equilibrium points, and determining the stability of each equilibrium point?

I found the equilibrium points x=0 and $x=1/kπ$, where k is integer.

$f'(x)=4x^3\sin(1/x)-x^4\cos(1/x)$.

When $k$ is 'even', $f'(x=1/kπ)=1/π^4$  which is positive, therefore **not** asymptotically stable.

And when $k$ is 'odd', $f'(x=1/kπ)=-1/π^4$ which is negative, therefore asymptotically stable.

But $f'(x=0)=0$, which is not hyperbolic. And *this* is the part that I can not solve.

Comment: Apply the definition of stability directly and consider that 0 is a limit point of stable equilibria.

Comment: Will it eventually be unstable at x=0 (that is my guess)? Can you explain how to use the delta-epsilon definition to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a small perturbation $x(t)$ of the zero solution, say with $x(0)=\epsilon \neq 0$. This solution will be caught in between two of the other equilibrium points (or perhaps exactly at one of them), and this lets you permit what happens to the solution $x(t)$ in the long run.

Comment: This is the very first question of Dynamical system that I am trying to solve. The examples in the lecture notes are not as complicated as this one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am still not sure how to continue (This is the very first question of Dynamical system that I am trying to solve. The examples in our lecture notes are not as complicated as this one). I am guessing that at very close to x=0 it is not stable because there will be always an odd and an even K which makes the f'(1/kπ) once negative and once positive respectively. So at one side of x=0 the arrow is toward the x=0, and at another side the arrow is away from x=0. Hence it will be unstable at x=0. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you have infinitely many equilibrium points that “pile up” as you approach the origin. In between these, the arrows alternatingly go left and right (since $x^4 \sin(1/x)$ oscillates between positive and negative values).